# If Statements and Gotos

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

```
set hunger=20
if "%hunger%" leq "4" goto hunger
```

It always sends me to hunger, even when I have more than 4. Help?

Comment: Did you have `:prepare` and `:shop`?

Comment: Please provide more code; otherwise it's impossible to see what's really going on...

Comment: @Cads: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31814455/edit) your question.

Comment: I know why it isn't working. It is going to a hunger point, because a variable is too low. It is set at 10, and it won't go there if it is below 5. Why is it not continuing?

Comment: by adding quotes, you force `if` to do a string comparison instead of number comparison.

Comment: you should be able to delete your question. But you shouldn't. After your edit it's a good and helpful question which might help others in the future. You can write (and accept) an answer to your own question.